# Tinymce Django textarea doesn't input tags

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, tinymce

I need some help implementing the TinyMCE textarea, to make it function in on my page.

Example:
[This is how it looks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l7i4x.png)

html code:

```
<textarea class="replytextarea" id="textarea-edit" placeholder="..." name="text"></textarea>
```

JS code:

```
<script src="//cdn.tinymce.com/4/tinymce.min.js"></script>
    <script>tinymce.init({
          selector: '#textarea-edit',
          height: 300,
          theme: 'modern',
          plugins: [
            'advlist autolink lists link image charmap print preview hr anchor pagebreak',
            'searchreplace wordcount visualblocks visualchars code fullscreen',
            'insertdatetime media nonbreaking save table contextmenu directionality',
            'emoticons template paste textcolor colorpicker textpattern imagetools'
          ],
          toolbar1: 'insertfile undo redo | styleselect | bold italic | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist outdent indent | link image',
          toolbar2: 'print preview media | forecolor backcolor emoticons',
          image_advtab: true,
          templates: [
            { title: 'Test template 1', content: 'Test 1' },
            { title: 'Test template 2', content: 'Test 2' }
          ],
          content_css: [
            '//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:300,300i,400,400i',
            '//www.tinymce.com/css/codepen.min.css'
          ]
         });
  </script>
```

Comment: What errors appear in the browser's console?

Comment: @MichaelFromin I don't get any console errors. Take a look at this image https://i.gyazo.com/85f09aa09ea86837606131ce10354f55.png it just doesn't accept the tags you get from Tiny MCE

Comment: So in the top of the picture you are placing HTML in a textarea?

Comment: Yes @michaelFromin, that's coming right from the textarea

Comment: Are you wanting the HTML to be rendered (e.g. not see the tags but see the results)?  Are you expected the textarea to turn into TinyMCE?  Its unclear what your exact issue is ... perhaps you could create a TinyMCE Fiddle or JS Fiddle that shows this in action?